# Datatables 'Show All' lengthMenu throws invalid json error

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables

My dataTables throws 'INVALID JSON' error sporadically when I select 'All' from lengthMenu select input. Does any one know what is causing the problem. The following is my dataTables script:

```js
    var dataTable = $('#info-table').DataTable({

        dom: 'lfrtipB',
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        orderable: false,
        ajax: {
            url: 'core.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {action: 'fetch'},
            dataType: 'json',
        },
        searchable: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],
    });
```

The following is also my serverside process:

```js
    $query = 'SELECT * from archive ';

        if (isset($_POST['search']['value'])) {
            $query .= 'WHERE sid LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" ';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['length']) and $_POST['length'] != -1) {
            $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST["start"] . ', ' . $_POST["length"] . ' ';
        }


    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $filteredrows = $statement->rowCount();
    $data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $subarray = array();
    $subarray[] = $row['sid'];
    $subarray[] = $row['fname'] .' '. $row['lname'];
    $data[] = $subarray;
}

$output = array(
    'draw'            => intval($_POST['draw']),
    'recordsTotal'    => $filteredrows,
    'recordsFiltered' => $dbs->getTotalRecords('students'),
    'data'            => $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
exit();
```

**Some Points**

1. I am using dataTables version 1.10
2. It just sometimes throws invalid json error (yet, as a tiny bug, it should be evaded).
3. When error is thrown, consulting Chrome's inspect panel, the json is returned successfully; however, it throws the invalid json error.
4. It is not just 'Show All' option, very rarely lengthmenu '100' also encounters the same problem. But most of the time, it works properly.
5. the dataTables never runs into error when I choose 10, 20, and 50 from lengthMenu select input.
6. There is no errors recorded in my 'PHP error log' file.
7. I have about 1000 rows in my dataTables.
8. I am using the latest version of WampServer (3.1.7), and running PHP 7.3.
9. Nothing special regarding the problem is available at StackOverflow or dataTables website.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: check what request is creating when you are selecting ALL

Comment: What do you mean, @Negi Rox? The request is the same as others. it returns back an array of data to the dataTables. The problem is, it sometimes throws the error, not always. When I look into the network and check the content of the php processing file, I think it is incomplete. I mean it does not return all of the data. What is confusing me is that it just sometimes throws this error. Please help. Many Thanks dear.

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of your length section: `...100, "All"]],`. You need to remove it.

Comment: It didn't bring about much change., dear @AndrewJames :((.

Comment: Dear @AndrewJames. Running Mozilla for test, it gives the same olf 'invalid json' error the moment I open the page. Then I notice that PhpStorm gives that famous 'copy authorization URL to clipboard. In Chrome and Edge, however, it just throws sporadic errors. Do you think I am getting the error from the IDE or from the Wamp or something.

Comment: You also have an extra comma here: `dataType: 'json',`. I am not saying this will solve the issue - but it will cause problems. And it may cause the real issue to be hidden. Check everywhere for extra commas like this.

Comment: when it's failing just check the request which is sent to the server. after that check qhat query is firing and the no. of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At times getting disappointed from this same old sickening dataTables error, once more I come to assure myself that dataTables 'invalid json' is not related to the plugin itself, and there definitely must be something else causing the problem. In my case, two factors were causing the problems. First, if you are using Phpstorm, it somehow restricts some files, and gives the message, "Copy authorization URL to the clipboard", for whatever reason. So, what you are gonna do is remove the port Phpstorm uses, for instance,  localhost:63342/site/index.php, where in this instance, ':63342' should be deleted, and then site evaluated and tested. Consequently, the main cause of sporadic dataTables' invalid json errors is Phpstorm port interventions. All the best.